# This white box appeared and I cant write in the middle of the code

Tags: visual-studio

Hi I got this problem in visual studio 2022 C# and this white box just appeared and I do not know how to get rid of it and I can barely write in my code because this box causes me to delete or exchange letters and not add.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brroW.png)

Answer (score 2):

Press the Insert key on your keyboard to toggle this. it will either be labeled ins or insert depending on the keyboard.